# HDMI monitor not detected on Buster (Lenovo laptop)

Tags: debian, hdmi

I have read and followed suggestions on a few forums, but I am still not able to get my Debian Buster to detect the monitor in the HDMI output (the monitor works on other laptops and on my desktop).

Hope the information below helps identifying the problem:

xrandr providers:

```
$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x45 cap: 0xb, Source Output, Sink Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 2 associated providers: 0 name:Intel
```

Video hardware:

```
$ lshw -c video
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:142 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4000000-a407ffff
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:130 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

PCI devices:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -iEA3 vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 630
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Lenovo GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] (GeForce GTX 1060 Max-Q 3GB)
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidia
```

Installing `nvidia-driver` from backports did not work. Neither did removing and re-installing  `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`. Can anyone help get the monitor detected?